# rdflib-jsonld generates spurious url when '<' is used in '@id'

Tags: python, url, filepath, json-ld, rdflib

I'm using rdflib-jsonld to parse some NoSQL data and insert into Sesame. This is the problematic portion of the code:

```
context = {
    "@context": {
    "isGiven": URIRef('<'+'http://purl.org/net/something#isGiven'+rdfLizerItem['FooByBar']+'>'),
    "administeredAs": URIRef('<'+'http://purl.org/net/something#administeredAs'+'>'),
    "type":URIRef('<'+'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type'+'>'),
    }
    }
    recipient=URIRef('<'+someUrl+rdfLizerItem['FooRecipient']+'>')
    jsonldOutputIsAdmin = {"@id": recipient,"isGiven": URIRef('<'+someUrl+ rdfLizerItem['Quantity']+'>')}
    print jsonldOutputIsAdmin
    g = Graph()
    g.parse(data=json.dumps(jsonldOutputIsAdmin), format='json-ld', context=context)
    g.close()
    for s,p,o in g:
        pprint.pprint ((s,p,o))
```

The issue is upon the addition of `<` and `>` to the URL for `@id`, the URL of the subject becomes the complete path to it. For example:

```
(rdflib.term.URIRef(u'file:///C:/path/to/the/url/<http:/purl.org/net/ontologyName#subject>'),
 rdflib.term.URIRef(u'<http://purl.org/net/ontologyName#predicate>'), 
rdflib.term.Literal(u'<http://purl.org/net/ontologyName#object>'))
```

I want only the URL in the subject and not the file path. What is causing the issue and how I can I resolve it?

I need `<` and `>` to be able to export the triples to Sesame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the filesystem path being applied as a prefix, you need to provide the context with a value for the [base IRI](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#base-iri)

> JSON-LD allows IRIs to be specified in a relative form which is
>   resolved against the document base according section 5.1 Establishing
>   a Base URI of [RFC3986]. The base IRI may be explicitly set with a
>   context using the @base keyword.

For example, if you modify your context like this:

`context['@context']['@base'] = '.'`

you won't see the path prefixing the @id value.